# Youtube Javascript API Embed has 2 title bars after video ends

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am having a problem with the JavaScript Embed API for youtube.  After a video has finished playing, there are two title bars at the top.  When playing, or when loaded, there is only 1 visible.  I have created a fiddle of this, but am clueless at this point at what could be effecting it.

Here is the barebones example - http://jsfiddle.net/BuM46/ :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.startVideo').click(function() {
        showVideoLightbox('twx2nkNZXQ0');
    });
})  

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag,firstScriptTag);

function showVideoLightbox(id)
{
    var player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', 
    {
        height: '375', width: '667',
        videoId: id,
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'rel': 0 }
    });
}
```

I don't even know where to start though since this is basically the most basic example of a youtube embed, even on their own documentation.  I've tried googling - 'Youtube JavaScript API embed 2 title bars' but that results in nothing useful.  The only thing I have noticed is if you take out the `'rel': 0` from the code, it actually works right.  Am I insane in thinking that this is a bug?

Any clarification or help I could get on this would be awesome, as this issue is currently evident on a high traffic state tourism site, and I am trying to fix it for my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some experimentation is leading me to assume this is a bug -- well, not so much a coding bug as a logic bug. It appears that, when the 'rel' parameter is set to not display related videos, the player assumes that it should add an info bar at the end of the video instead -- so if you already have an info bar (which is the default), you get the double bar. One temporary workaround that may suffice your needs would be to embed the video without the info bar:

```
playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0 }
```

That way, when the info bar is added at the end, it won't be doubled. Obviously it isn't completely ideal since you may want the info bar to show up when the video is playing, but it might be the best for now. You may also want to report the issue to confirm it is, in fact, a bug.

Comment: Bug, yeah, that's what I was thinking.  At least I am not insane this time.  I didn't realize that that was the info bar.  If I had known that, I would have had a better Google query, and at least probably would have tried that `showinfo` fix.  Of course I suppose I could've searched for elements in an embedded youtube player!  This will work for now, but I hope Google fixes it soon. Thanks!

Comment: As of yesterday, this appears to be fixed in the YouTube JS API now.  The bug I had input on gdata bug tracker never got replied to by Google, but its working now.